The remote server returned an error: (400) Forbidden in PowerShell when running a script
I am trying to get a report of all Teams chats in my school between teachers and students. This is the script I am running in PowerShell.
# Define your tenant ID, client ID, and client secret
$tenantId = "tenantID"       # Replace with your actual tenant ID
$clientId = "clientId"       # Replace with your actual client ID
$clientSecret = "clientSecret" # Replace with your actual client secret

# Get the access token
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
}

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $tokenResponse.access_token

# Set the headers for the API request
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}

# Define the date range for the messages
$startDate = "2023-09-01T00:00:00Z"
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

# Get the list of chats
$chatsUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats"
$chatsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $chatsUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get
$chats = $chatsResponse.value

$allMessages = @()

foreach ($chat in $chats) {
    $chatId = $chat.id
    $messagesUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/$chatId/messages?\$filter=createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate"
    $messagesResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $messagesUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get
    $messages = $messagesResponse.value
    $allMessages += $messages
}

# Filter messages between teachers and students
$filteredMessages = $allMessages | Where-Object { $_.from.user.displayName -match "teacher" -and $_.to.user.displayName -match "student" }
$filteredMessages | Export-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\TeamsMessagesReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation

I am getting the following error.
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:29 char:18
+ ... sResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $chatsUrl -Headers $headers -Metho ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

I am a novice at PowerShell scripts but see no other way to get my head of school a reporet of all our Teams chats between Teachers and Students. Any ideas?
